# Linked list delete in C

Tags: c, linked-list, dynamic-allocation

Here's my code, I don't know whats wrong with it. When I "delete" an item in the list using keyboard input, it changes other item's name. Also when I input a name that is not on the list it will delete items. How to fix it?

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <conio.h>
     #include <string.h>
     #include <ctype.h>
     #include <stdlib.h>
    struct list
   {
char name[20];
int age;
char gender[10];
   struct list *next;
   };

   void main(void)
    {
   struct list *HEAD = NULL;
   struct list *temp,*current, *trav;
   struct list *prev;

     char choice;


while(1)
{
    clrscr();
    printf("MENU\n");
    printf("A) ADD\n");
    printf("B) DISPLAY\n");
    printf("C) DELETE\n");
    printf("X) EXIT\n");

    scanf("%c", &choice);
    switch(toupper(choice))
{
 case 'A':
            temp= (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
            temp->next=NULL;
            printf("Fill-Up the following:\n");
            printf("Name:");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(temp->name);
            printf("Age:");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%d",&temp->age);
            printf("Gender:");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(temp->gender);


            if(HEAD == NULL)
            {
                      HEAD = temp;

            }
            else if(HEAD!=NULL)
            {
              for(trav=HEAD; trav->next != NULL; trav= trav->next);
              trav->next=temp;
            }
            else
            {
            printf("Not Enough Memory!\n");
            }


 break;
 case 'B':

          if(HEAD==NULL)
          {
          printf("Linked List is Empty!\n");
          getch();
          }
          else{
          for(trav=HEAD; trav != NULL; trav=trav->next )
          {

                printf("\nName: %s\n", trav->name);
                printf("Age: %d\n", trav->age);
                printf("Gender: %s\n\n", trav->gender);
                     }
                     getch();

          }

 break;

case 'C' :
    if(HEAD==NULL)
    {
    printf("No item to be delete. List is Empty!\n");
    getch();
        }
    else {
        printf("Enter The Name of the item you want to Delete: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(temp->name);
        current=HEAD;

        if(strcmp(temp->name,current->name)== 0)
        {
            HEAD=HEAD->next;
            free(current);
            printf("Item has been successfully deleted from the list.\n");
            getch();
            }
        else
         {
            for(prev=HEAD,trav=HEAD->next; strcmp(trav->name,temp->name)!=0 ; trav=trav->next,prev=prev->next);
                  if(trav==NULL)
                  {
                  printf("Name: %s not found!", temp->name);
                  getch();
                  }
                  else{
                prev->next=trav->next;
                free(trav);
                printf("Item has been successfully deleted from the list.\n");
                getch();
                }

            }
        }
    break;
 case 'X':
 if(HEAD!=NULL){free(HEAD); }
if(trav!=NULL){ free(trav);   }
   if(temp!=NULL){ free(temp);  }
 exit(1);

 break;

}

}
```

}

Comment: What don't you write a individual function for each task, Like add, delete, print ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get name of the item to delete you do `gets(temp->name);`. But `temp` points to last item that you added in the list. So when you read the name in `temp->name` the last item's name will change.

To correct the behavior, allocated new item and add that in the linked list.

Comment: ah. its okay now. thanks, but why is it that in the statement `if(trav==NULL)` it doesn't print the `temp->name` ? it says "Name: (null) not Found."?